# Generic function and attribute with Equatable and Printable as parameters in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to write a function that allow any objects but must be `Printable` and `Equatable` array of objects in Swift?

```
class func withItems(items: [AnyObject]){

}
```

1. I need items to be `Printable` and `Equatable`
2. I need to declare that items array as attribute of my class

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generic constraints to require both protocols in a function:

```
class func withItems<T: AnyObject where T: Equatable, T: Printable>(items: [T]) {
    // ...
}
```

Requiring that of a stored property is trickier, since `Equatable` can't be used as a type. In order to do so you'd essentially need to make the class itself generic. You'd probably be better off declaring `items` as an array of `AnyObject` and providing access to it through generic methods like this one.

Comment: But I get `T is not identical to AnyObject` if I have an stored property of type `[AnyObject]`

Comment: AnyObject is just another protocol - can you try `<T: AnyObject where T: Equatable, T: Printable>`?

Comment: There's a problem when I try to get description from the object. The items array is: `var items: [AnyObject] ` and if I try items[indexPath.row].description it prints the Object default description, not the override one. If I do a manual cast to the object type it prints right, but if I left it as AnyObject it prints the default, why?

Comment: I "solve it" creating another array with the descriptions inside the method like this: `controller.titles = items.map( { $0.description } )`