# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION object array assign Swift

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, exc-bad-instruction

I have an array of Printable objects, but I need them Equatable and AnyObject compliant.

```
private(set) var items: [Printable] = []

class func withItems<T: AnyObject where T: Equatable, T: Printable>(items: [T], selectedItem: T? = nil) {
   ... instance init ...
   instance.items = items
}
```

And it result on EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION:

> fatal error: array cannot be bridged from Objective-C

This is one try to this problems:

- [Generic function and attribute with Equatable and Printable as parameters in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27319588/generic-function-and-attribute-with-equatable-and-printable-as-parameters-in-swi)

why?

Comment: What is your purpose of using `self` at `class func` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Swift Array must contain all one kind of object (e.g. all String or all Int). An Objective-C NSArray can contain many different kinds of objects (e.g. some NSStrings and some NSNumbers). Hence if you get that kind of array from Objective-C you can't magically assign it into a Swift array reference.

What I do in that situation is munge the array to make it acceptable to Swift. I don't know what the details are of what you're getting back from Objective-C; your actual strategy will depend on those details and what you want to do with the array. One approach is to assign / cast into a Swift array of AnyObject. Or you might decide to leave it as an NSArray and work with it entirely through NSArray methods.

Here's an example from my own code. `arr` is an NSArray that's a mixed bag of NSString and NSNull objects. I know none of the NSString objects are the empty string, so I substitute the empty string for all the NSNull objects, thus giving me an array of just strings, which Swift can deal with:

```
let arr2 = (arr as Array).map { $0 as? String ?? "" }
```

Now `arr2` is a pure Swift `[String]` array.